# If Else scripting parameters CMD

Tags: cmd

I'm new to scripting and i want 1 script for weekly and daily backups. I want to use parameters in the task scheduler to run the correct backup and set the correct locations for the backup. Daily backup has a different folder location, that's why i'm working with parameters. How can i define this like:

If parameter is $true

set destination: \server\weekly

Else

set destination: \server\daily

Comment: I want to learn powershell but this script was allready produced and i need to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use %1 as input parameter , for example:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
   •
   • Here your batch file handles %1
   •
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

**Or in your Case:**

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="Daily" GOTO Daily
IF "%1"=="Weekly" GOTO Weekly


:Daily
echo Daily Worker
GOTO EOF


:Weekly
echo Weekly Worker


:EOF
echo Done!
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer. so i can use:

@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
  set destination \\server1\share\weekly
  set logfile \\server1\share\weekly
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue

set destination \\server2\share\daily\
set logfile \\server2\share\daily

like this?

Comment: Sorry if i ask but, how can i use the parameter for weekly or daily now? Do i need to create a task with parameters like %daily and %weekly?

Comment: @WantedBaby you call it like `mybatch.cmd Daily` or `mybatch.cmd Weekly`

Comment: @HansKesting So if i use the script above like:
scripting.cmd

:Daily
Set location \\server1\share

:weekly
Set location \\server2\share

And i give the task a name and locating to scripting.cmd daily it will work?

Comment: @WantedBaby You need to use `SET location=\\server1\share` (mind the `=`). Don't forget the `GOTO EOF` to skip the "weekly" assignment. And the rest of the processing after the `:EOF` label

Comment: @HansKesting  I made it work thank you!, Daily and Weekly. Only the next problem is that the -include:C: or -exclude:D: doesn't work. I deleted the -include:C:,D: in the script and want to add it in the parameters. Anybody know how to do this? There is a -backuptarget in it so it must work.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the question is not cmd.exe script nor is it PowerShell. I am assuming that you are modifying a cmd.exe shell script.

```
IF "%1" EQU "TRUE" DO (
    SET "DESTINATION=\\server\weekly"
) ELSE (
    SET "DESTINATION=\\server\daily"
)
```

Comment: I made it work thank you!, Daily and Weekly. Only the next problem is that the -include:C: or -exclude:D: doesn't work. I deleted the -include:C:,D: in the script and want to add it in the parameters. Anybody know how to do this? There is a -backuptarget in it so it must work

Comment: The question does not say anything about "-include:C:" or "-exclude:D:" Rather than editing this question, please create a new question.